# Android, Firebase сервис push уведомлений

Tags: java, android, firebase

Делаю пуш рассылку на приложение через *Firebace*, мне необходимо чтобы когда пользователь нажимает на сообщение открывалась нужная мне активити (не главное активити).

Сейчас это реализовано так

```
<activity
        android:name=".StereoIntroActivity"
        android:label="">
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:name=".firebace.MessagingService">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

В данном классе MessagingService реализован сервис, который должен получение слушать сообщения. Вот его код

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StereoIntroActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(StereoActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle("asasasasas!!!!") //this.getString(R.string.app_name)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы открывалось `StereoIntroActivity`, но почему-то открывается главное активити, мне вообще кажется что этот сервис просто не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём у меня проблема.
 Заранее большое спасибо!

update. вот так отправляю сообщение
[image: firebase отправка]

Comment: Там два способа. Посылать в json поле нотификатин или дата. Лучше второе, т.к. больше контроля. Если первое, то надо интенетом то настроить в манифест и кликАстион в поле нотификатион

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вот я правильно понимаю, что нужно в методе sendNotification прописать clickAction? Просто не совсем очевидно как это сделать и мн кажется, что этот метод не отрабатывает, так как я в .setContentTitle("asasasasas!!!!")  ставлю абракадабру, но она не отображается при получении пуша

Comment: попробуйте добавить флаг NEW_TASK -
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: @Rumato, не совсем. Вам надо на стороне FireBase нстроить уведомление. Именно там надо clickAction прописать. Покажите как вы отправляете пуш

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть 2 разных способа отправить сообщение с помощью FireBase. Первый способ - отправить информацию в теле пуша в поле `notification` - так инфа будет обработана FireBase-ом мочла, без вызова метода `onReceive`. JSON должен выглядеть так:

```
{ "notification": {
    "title": "news",
    "text": "newsTExt",
     "click_action": "test"
  },
    "data": {
    "keyname": "any value"
    },
  "to" : "dAQilNw:APA91IFd666h7WVSlAOyS-WraSrGv_IRZM"
}
```

Так отобразится уведомление, которое направит юзера в активити с `intentFilter` `test`, как это указано в поле `click_action`. Если не будет в манифесте активити с таким фильтром - запустится главная актвити.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="test"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

---

Второй способ - отправлять информацию в поле `data` без поля `notification` - так точно будет вызван метод `onReceive` в котором вы можете уже отреагировать на пуш нужным образом, самостоятельно отобразив уведомление. В т.ч. составить `PendingIntent` для запуска нужной активити.

---

Через саму консоль FireBase отпрвлять пуши не очень, т.к. там мало что понятно и мало контроля. Лучше отправлять запрос через программу `Postman` - она есть в т.ч. в виде приложения для браузера Хром.

1. Для этого надо через Postman отправить POST запрос на адрес
   https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
2. При этом надо задать заголовки

```
Authorization = key=%тут ключ который можно взять из консоли (Настройки-настройки проекта-CLOUD MESSAGING-ключ сервера)%
ContentType = application/json
```

3. Далее в теле (`body`) запроса, в `raw` формате отправлять `json` с данными, в виде, описанном выше.

Comment: сейчас я отправляю через личный кабинет в firebase, там в дополнительных настройках указываю "click_action": "test", но почему-то пока всё так же работает (запускается только главное активити)

Comment: @Rumato, покажите в вопросе как вы это делаете. У вас в манифесте фильтр прописан? Приложение свёрнуто/прибито при этом?

Comment: я добавил в вопрос информацию, скрин консоли и что в манифесте

Comment: и когда я отправляю сообщение приложение свёрнуто

Comment: @Rumato, я обновил ответ с инфой о том как правильно отправлять пуш

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, а в это поле  "to" : что писать?

Comment: @Rumato, туда надо положить токен девайса. Получать его как-то так надо: `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, вы мне очень помогли!