# Отправка Push-уведомлений через FCM (Не через консоль!!!)

Tags: java, android, http, firebase, firebase-android

Необходимо отправить push уведомление без помощи консоли!!!
Из самого андроид приложения описать описать структуру PUSH уведомления, чтобы его получил другой пользователь.

Есть код для получения, когда приложение активно. А как сделать так, чтобы отправить не через консоль firebase.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

 Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.icon))
        .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за предложенную статью. Но это абсолютно не то, что мне нужно. Мне надо отправить push уведомление не через консоль, а со смартфона

Comment: В ответе по ссылке из дубликата рассказано как составить нужный запрос к FIreBase для отправки пуша без использования консоли FireBase, а через программу Postman. Там описаны все параметры запроса - адрес, заголовки, тело. Если вам надо из приложения - просто отправьте этот запрос из приложения. Например для этого можно использовать либу OkHttp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается запрос с помощью либы `OkHttp` так:

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

//в JSON в качесвте значения поля "to" должен быть токен девайса-цели.
//его можно получить как-то так: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); 
String json = "{ 
   \"notification\": {
    \"title\": \"news\",
    \"text\": \"newsTExt\",
     \"click_action\": \"test\"
  },
    \"data\": {
    \"keyname\": \"any value\"
    },
  \"to\" : \"dAQilNw:APA91IFd666h7WVSlAOyS-WraSrGv_IRZM\"
}"

String keyFromConsole = ...;//тут ключ который можно взять из консоли (Настройки-настройки проекта-CLOUD MESSAGING-ключ сервера)

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
      .addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + keyFromConsole)
      .addHeader("ContentType", "application/json")
      .post(body)
      .build();


Response response = client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

  @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }

  @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
});
```

---

Вот ещё полезная инфа: [Android, Firebase сервис push уведомлений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607320/17609)

Comment: Большое спасибо, сейчас все попробую)

Comment: Большое спасибо, Юрий, все получилось. Однозначно лайк