# Firebase Notifications

Tags: android, firebase

Я сделал меню, в котором пользователи выбирают какие уведомления они хотят получать.

Уведомления я всегда отправляю с опрделённым ключом: WEB-получать уведомления от сайта, SHOP-от магазина.

С помощью SharedPreference сохраняю значения меню: какие уведомления пользователь хочет получать.

Собственно в FirebaseMessagingService что-то получилось, но он отвечает за получение уведомления на переднем плане, а вот как отследить эти уведомления, когда приложение выключено не знаю.

Есть ли какой способ?

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService implements Constants{

    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sp = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_SETTINGS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean webSite = sp.getBoolean(notifWebSite, true);
        boolean shops = sp.getBoolean(notifShops, true);
        if(webSite && shops){
            if(remoteMessage.getData().equals("WEB")){
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getData().get("WEB"));
            }
            if (remoteMessage.getData().equals("SHOP")){
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getData().get("SHOP"));
            }
        }
        else if(!webSite && !shops){

        }
        else if(!webSite && shops){
            if(remoteMessage.getData().equals("SHOP")){
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getData().get("WEB"));
            }
        }
        else if(webSite && !shops){
            if(remoteMessage.getData().equals("WEB")){
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getData().get("WEB"));
            }
        }



        /*if(remoteMessage.getData().get("URL")==null){
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),URL_HODITE_COM);
        }
        else{
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getData().get("URL"));
        }*/

    }

    private void sendNotification(String body,String url) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,url);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) //Время уведомления
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(body); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
// ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify((body+url).hashCode(),notification);
    }


}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы отправляете пуши, свой бекенд или через какой-то сервис? В общем суть в том, что если в пуше не будет ключа "notification", а будет только "data", то все пуши будут попадать в ваш сервис, независимо от того свёрнуто приложение или на переднем плане.

Comment: @eugeneek добавил скрин в вопрос.
Я с помощью Firebase отправляю уведомление.
Если есть возможность все пуши отправлять в FirebaseMessagingService при открытом и закрытом приложении, расскажите пожалуйста, я с радостью переделаю своё приложение

Comment: Не нашёл возможности в консоле убрать тег "notification". Думаю для вашего случая подойдут [темы](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). То есть, при изменении настроек подписываться/отписываться на нужную тему (WEB/SHOP), а при отправке указывать нужную.

Comment: @shcherbuk, вот тут, вроде, то, что вам нужно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607320/17609

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо @eugeneek, помогли **ТЕМЫ**.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("НАЗВАНИЕ ТЕМЫ") // подписать
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("НАЗВАНИЕ ТЕМЫ") // отписать
```