# FCM получить данные уведомления не нажимая на уведомление

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android, fcm

В приложении реализована отправка пуш-сообщений с помощью **Firebase Messaging Service**. Подскажите, как получить данные уведомления, не нажимая на само уведомление. Я знаю, как получить данные при нажатии на уведомление или когда приложение в Foreground'e. Интересно, когда приложение в background'e.

Comment: Посмотрите 2 способ в ответе тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607320/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у меня сообщение содержит 2 типа, чтобы обрабатываться как в бэкграунде, так и в фореграунде. Когда пришло уведомление и я открываю приложение, я ничего не вижу в Extras, если открываю по нажатию на уведомление - то все ОК.

Comment: Последний раз я с этим возился около года назад и пришёл в итоге к тому, чтобы обрабатывать только одним способом - вручную. Т.е. всё в `data` отправлять и вручную уведомления формировать и отображать - тогда всё работает и нет разницы в поведении независимо от состояния приложения.

Answer (score 0):

В приложении должен быть класс наследник FirebaseMessagingService в котором переопределяешь метод onMessageReceived в этот метод заходит объект RemoteMessage из которого вынимаешь инфу.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   //этот метод отрабатывает всегда когда заходит push
 }   
}
```

Не забываем в манифесте прописать

```
<service
        android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```