# Структура пуш уведомления

Tags: android, fcm

Через консоль fcm создаю уведомление. В разделе "канал передачи уведомления на android" передаю данные, которые буду использовать для pendingIntent. Где мне найти их в RemoteMessage.Notification?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше всего вообще не пользоваться консолью для отправки пушей. Оно очень обрезанное. Лучше напрямую дёргать API пушей для отправки оных. Вот тут описано как: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607320/17609

Comment: это не моё пожелание. как сказали так и делаю. пуши будут отправлять вручную.

Comment: В таком случае ничем помочь не могу( За годы практики ни разу не видел что бы кто пользовался консолью для отправки пушей. В основном потому, что такие пуши в случае работы приложения в фоне невозможно программно обработать, что неприемлемо в 99% случаев.